# Dynamically set method on before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

In my controller i want to dynamically bind my instance method to the before_save callbacks.

Is there any ways we can dynamically bind methods to the callback from controller side....

### EDIT :

Controller

This original code..

```
def amfupdate
  set_properties
  validate_record  if params[:csv_header][:validate_record] == "Y" #On this condition...
  super
end
```

If condition is true than i want to set custom callback that will exact call after before_save but before object is saved.

I want to call this method exact after before_save.. But if condition is true on controller side ..

In Model

```
def validate_record
  self.csv_columns.each do |csv_column|
    self.errors.add_to_base(_("Invalid column name #{csv_column.column_name}.")) \
      unless self.model_name.constantize.column_names.include?(csv_column.column_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems that you are doing something wrong — try to avoid business logic in controller.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you give an example of what you mean or are trying to achieve?

Comment: I woudl still repeat what tig said, you're trying to do something in the controller that you should do in the model. You should set up the validate as aregular validation, and use other methods to decide whether or not to override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the following. In the Model:

```
validate do |instance|
  instance.csv_columns.each do |csv_column|
    instance.errors.add :csv_columns, "Invalid column name #{csv_column.column_name}"
      unless instance.class.column_names.include?(csv_column.column_name)
  end
end
```

This will be called before the record is saved and will abort the save if the errors are added to

UPDATE: With suggestion for conditional validations

Add an attribute to the model

```
attr_accessor :some_condtional
```

Set this in the controller

```
@instance.some_conditional = true # or false
```

Then the validation now looks like this:

```
validate do |instance|
  instance.csv_columns.each do |csv_column|
    instance.errors.add :csv_columns, "Invalid column name #{csv_column.column_name}"
      unless instance.class.column_names.include?(csv_column.column_name)
  end if instance.some_conditional
end
```

Or something along those lines. In other words use the model to hold the state and communicate the logic

Comment: But i want to execute this part only if my controller side condition is true... how may i set that??